# How can I profile a Blazor page load?

Tags: blazor, resharper, blazor-server-side, dottrace

If there was no database queries I would just fire up the dotTrace profiler, start it, and keep clicking the link on my page to keep going to that page 20 or so times. It's not perfect, but it's close.

But unless something has been added, dotTrace is useless to tell me how long each DB query is taking. So how can I measure that?

And if dotTrace misses other parts of a Blazor page creating & rendering, what else do I need to measure and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please use Timeline profiling type? Do the SQL Queries events persist in the snapshot?

You can read more about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2023.3/SQL_Client.html

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want/need - thanks